# What approaches could be taken to disable actual scrolling when using hotkey+scroll to zoom in XFCE?

Tags: xubuntu, shortcut-keys, touchpad, xfce, mouse-wheel

I am thrilled that XFCE allows you to hold the ALT key and scroll the mouse or trackpad to zoom!  I absolutely adore the simplicity of this feature and I use it daily.

However, one issue I regularly have is that the content of whatever is below the cursor begins to also respond with the scroll event.  This makes it very difficult to inspect anything when page contents move away from the screen position they started in.

I was thinking that I could stop this from happening at the application-level in something like Chrome with a simple Greasemonkey key-listener script since this would not impact the system-level event.  The trouble is, this problem also happens in many other frequently used programs like Thunar and VS Code.

Is there some way I can bind a hotkey event to disable scroll across the system while at the same time not breaking the zoom feature's ability to read that event?  I'm afraid I don't know enough about this topic to find meaningful search results.

Answer (score 0):

First open **Window Manager Tweaks** and go to **Accessiibility** Tab

Go to Window Manager Tweaks
[image]

After That, change the **Key used to grab and move windows** to other than **Alt** key

I Change it to Shift Key
[image]